# checking if an iframe exists and then creating HTML markup using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create the HTML markup using jquery:

```
<div class="icon"></div>
```

If the youtube video exists on the page then create the above markup:

```
if ($('div.container iframe').length) {
  alert('frame exists');
  $('<div class="icon"></div>');
}
```

However its not create the markup.
I want the user to paste a youtube video then my Jquery should create the icon automatically for them. Please look at my implementation:

```
var $video = $('div.container iframe');  //location of video
var $productImage = $('.product-image'); //location of main prod img
var $icon = $('.icon');                  //location of icon

//check if video exists
if ($('div.container iframe').length) {
    alert('frame exists');
  $('<div class="icon"></div>');

}

$('.product-image').append($video);      //append the video to the main prod img

$icon.on('click', function() {           //click
    $video.toggle();                     //toggle the video based on click
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/t7qMF/7/
**SOLUTION:** http://jsfiddle.net/t7qMF/13/

Comment: div.icon has its own css, so you should see an icon appear on the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First check if iframe exists or not and if exists then `append` icon div -

```
if ($('div.container iframe').length > 0) {
    alert('frame exists');
    $('.container').append('<div class="icon">Icon</div>');
}
```

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/t7qMF/11/

Answer (score 0):

`$('<div class="icon"></div>');` creates the markup but doesn't put it any where. Append that to something and it should work.